# Unable to hear any sound through speakers or any other device

Tags: windows-8, audio, sound-card

I am unable to hear sound from my speakers which are plugged in to rear panel of my PC, all was working fine (even I didn’t had Realtek installed) but suddenly it stopped giving any sound, than I installed Realtek drivers but still no sound.

- In Realtek sound manager rear panel is disabled no matter what I do
  I can't access them
- It shows headphones are plugged into front panel, but nothing is plugged into front panel
- Even if I plugged them into front panel even thn no sound (but front panels never worked for me so I don't think they are part of this problem)
- When my PC starts at the time when there as to be sound, instead there is only some little 'dib dib ..' like little noise that comes out, like some thing is sent to the speakers
- My speakers are fine and I have check them with other devices.

[image]

Comment: The reason the backpanel is not working is because its disabled.  Only the front panel is enabled per the screenshot.  As the reason it was working and now its not, that could be explained by the fact, hardware can fail.  The fact you are getting artifact noise points to a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that might be a hardware problem. Check the sound card's audio microchip for traces of burning or any other damage. If you see damage, you're going to have to either buy a new sound card or replace the motherboard.